# Ошибка компилятора при присваивании итератору значения из map::find в const функции

Tags: c++, stl, map, const, итераторы

В константной функции при попытке присвоить полученный итератор из map::find локальному итератору получаю ошибку компилятора.
Если функцию сделать не константной, то ошибки нет.

```
class A
{
public:
    double get(const uint16_t id) const;
private:
    std::map<uint16_t, double> mMap;
};

double A::get(const uint16_t id) const
{
    std::map<uint16_t, double>::iterator iter;
    iter = mMap.find(id); // здесь ошибка

    if(iter != mMap.end())  return iter -> second;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что внутри константного метода пытаетесь получить неконстантный итератор. В STL у всех контейнеров есть константные итераторы, например в в Вашем случае

```
 map<uint16_t, double>::const_iterator.
```

А вообще проще использовать в таких случаях auto для автовыведения типа.